Conditional expectations between Ito diffusions
If one has
$dX_t = f(Y_t)\mu_1(X_t, t)dt + \sigma_1(X_t, t)dW_t$
$dY_t = \mu_2(Y_t, t) + \sigma_2(Y_t, t) dW_t$
driven by the same Brownian motion. Is it sensible to consider a conditional expectation of the type $Z_t = \mathbb{E}[X_t | Y_t = y_t]$ ?
Furthermore, is it sensible to consider $Z_t$ as satisfying an equation like:
$dZ_t = f(y_t) \mathbb{E}[(X_t, t) | Y_t = y_t]dt + \mathbb{E}[\sigma_1(X_t, t)dW_t | Y_t = y_t]$
What does conditioning do to the $dW_t$ term? If this was simply $\mathbb{E}$, then the entire diffusion term vanishes and I formally have a sort of ODE. The specific nature of this example I am willing to adjust if any of it is nonsense, but in general I am interested in understanding what I can say about
$$\mathbb{E} [X_t | Y_t ]$$ for $X_t, Y_t$ stochastic processes defined by an Ito SDE.
Here is an example that seems to work:
$$dX_t = Y_t X_t dt$$
$$dY_t = dW_t$$
This easily can be seen to have solution $X_t = \exp(\int_0^t Y_s ds)$ and $Y_t = W_t$. It is indeed the case that if I was to condition on the event $W_t = \omega_t$, then the solution of the equation
$$dZ = \omega_t Z_t dt$$
$Z_t = \exp(\int_0^t \omega_s ds)$ is indeed the conditional expectation of the directly calculated $X_t$.

Of course it is sensible to consider the conditional expectation $Z_t = \mathbb{E}[X_t | Y_t = y_t],.$ Your equation for $dZ_t$ is close to nonsense. What are the random variables there you are taking the conditional expectations of?

Well what it really mean is taking the expectation of the integral equation for $X$, commuting $\int, \mathbb{E}$. Since any function $Y_t$ ought to be measurable w.r.t to the sigma algebra, I am inclined to think I can pull it out like constants.

How about an attempt then? Choosing $\mu_1,\mu_2,\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ so that we have two explicit solutions should be of great help. No formal symbol pushing please.

The easiest example I can think of is making $X_t$ an OU process with $Y_t$ dependent linear coefficient and making $Y_t$ Brownian motion, but this won't have any explicit solution. The main thing is I want to know what I can do with with conditional expectation vs just expectation for SDEs, since I know it to be true that were $Y_t \equiv y_t$ deterministic, I could take $\mathbb{E}$ and derive the formal ODE $\partial_t Z_t = f(y_t) \mathbb{E}[\mu_1(X_t,t)]$.

I still have not freed you from the symbol pushing mode. 1) In the edited question, $Z_t = \exp(\int_0^t \omega_s,ds)$ is the conditional expectation of $X_t = \exp(\int_0^t W_s,ds)$ when you condition $X_t$ on the entire path of $W$ from zero to $t,.$ In your notation you conditioned on $W_t$ only. 2) An SDE gives rise to a (not only formal) ODE for the expectation if and only if the drift is affine linear. That is because the expectation of the $dW$-term is zero. Think about how much of this carries over to the conidtional expectation.

I am perfectly happy to condition on the entire sample path, in fact that could even be preferable.  What would the correct notation to express this, and what would happen if I did not have $\sigma_1 = 0$, how would I condition on this? Your second point eludes me, is this like an existence of a strong solution where the coefficients are taken to be linear growth that you are getting at?

A strong solution of an SDE $dX_t=\mu_1(X_t,t),dt+\sigma_1(X_t,t),dW_t$ is a functional $X_t=F(X_0,t,W)$ of the entire path of $W$ until $t,.$ If you condition that on the entire path you will get $Z_t=X_t,.$ See Karatzas & Shreve, Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus, the chapter containing the Yamada-Watanabe theorem.

By conditioning on $Y_t = y_t$ (the entire sample path) I am implicitly fixing a realisation of $W_t$ no? whatever the value $\omega_t$ such that the functional (for the $Y$ SDE) $G(Y_0, t, \omega) = y_t$. Does this mean it is correct that $\mathbb{E}[X_t | Y_t = y_t ] = \mathbb{E}[F(X_0, t, W) | Y_t = y_t] = \mathbb{E}[F(X_0, t, W) | W_t = \omega_t] = F(X_0, t, \omega_t) $ ?

My comment answers the question when $Y_t=W_t,.$ The case when $Y_t$ is itself a functional of $W$ I left open. Think about it. Use explicit examples as already recommended.
